# Fetch input URL to img scr

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

i am trying to get the URL from the input field to the SRC of img tag.

```
<input id="load"> // here we type the URL of image
<input type="submit">
  <img id="my-image" onclick="doit()" src='' />
```

Comment: Welcome, but SO is not a code-writing service! Please describe, what did you try and insert your [code](/help/reprex) to the question, if you have any. If you haven't, then search for a tutorial on another site, and come back to us, with some code! Also read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function doit() {
  // get the value of the input
  const {value} = document.getElementById('load');
  // set the src on the img
  document.getElementById('my-image').src = value;
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
input {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input id="load" value="http://placekitten.com/200" />
<button onClick="doit()">go</button>
<img id="my-image" src="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your function up to the submit button rather than the image.

```js
function doit(){

  // grab the url from the input
  var url = document.getElementById("load").value;
  
  // load the image from the input url
  document.getElementById("my-image").src = url;
  
}
```

```html
<input id="load"> // here we type the URL of image
<input type="submit" onclick="doit()">
<img id="my-image"  src='' />
```